# Neo4j Cypher Relationship syntax

Tags: neo4j

https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/get-started/cypher/#cypher-intro-patterns-relationship-syntax

The Neo4j Developer Manual section 2.2.1.2 describes the syntax for Relationships. I have a question regarding the 4th example as copied below.

```
-[role:ACTED_IN {roles: ["Neo"]}]->
```

What do the square brackets surrounding `["Neo"]` denote? Is this the syntax for an array? If so, how do we identify the elements of this array?

Basically, I'm trying to understand the difference between the above relationship and the one below.

```
-[role:ACTED_IN {roles: "Neo"}]->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an array, you're matching an `ACTED_IN` relationship which has a property called `roles` whose value is an array with one String element equal to `"Neo"` 
If you want to match any element in the array you would change this to 
`WHERE "Neo" IN role.roles`

In the second example, you're matching a property called `roles` whose value is simply a String equalling `"Neo"`